# Remove characters off tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using tinyMCE, whatever you type inside a box gets displayed in a tinyMCE box, I am retrieving the data by `tinyMCE.get('idname').getContent();` but its showing me the text as `<p>text</p>` how would I remove those p from my text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `format` option set to `text` to the getContent function:

```
var textOnly = tinyMCE.get('idname').getContent({format : 'text'});
```

Demonstrated in this fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/8leaab

Answer (score 0):

If `.getContent({format:'text'})` [doesn't work](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25140), try this:

```
var editor = tinyMCE.get('idname').getBody();
var text;
if(editor.textContent)
    text = editor.textContent;
else if(editor.innerText)
    text = editor.innerText;
```

or since you're using jQuery

```
var editor = tinyMCE.get('idname').getBody();
var text;
text = $(editor).text();
```